How to create environment variables with the the package vlucas/phpdotenv for yii2 advance template
I installed the package:
composer require vlucas/phpdotenv
and in the root of my project i have a .env file with some configuration variable.
Now i try to use PHP dotenv to get the ENV variable availables to the prod and dev environments.
So, to do this, i've modified the yii file inside of environments/dev and environments/prod folders in order to get env variables available inside the project.
So the yii file is :
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
/**
 * Yii console bootstrap file.
 */
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
require __DIR__ . '/common/config/bootstrap.php';
require __DIR__ . '/console/config/bootstrap.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__ . '/');
$dotenv->load();

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/common/config/main.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/common/config/main-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/console/config/main.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/console/config/main-local.php'
);

$application = new yii\console\Application($config);
$exitCode = $application->run();
exit($exitCode);

For example i modified my main-local.php inside environments\common folder
'db' => [
            'class' => \yii\db\Connection::class,
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$_ENV['DB_NAME'],
            'username' => $_ENV['DB_USER'],
            'password' => $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'],
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'enableSchemaCache' => $_ENV['DB_USE_CACHE'],
            'schemaCacheDuration' => 3600,
            'schemaCache' => 'cache',
        ],

But when i run php init  $_ENV variable is empty. Is this the correct way to set .env file? what am I doing wrong?
This is my .env file
# APPLICATION CONFIG
APP_NAME="Yii -CMS"
APP_LANGUAGE=it
APP_CHARSET=utf-8
APP_ENV=dev # [dev | test | prod]
APP_DEBUG=true # use 'false' in production

# DATABASE CONFIG
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=''
DB_NAME=yiicms
DB_USE_CACHE=false # use 'true' in production


init and yii scripts are completely different files. yii script serves as entry point for console app while init is script that initializes config files for new application.
